# Java ProcessBuilder on Mac OSX doesn't see Python 3

Tags: java, python, macos, python-3.x, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a Python script from Java using ProcessBuilder. The script requires Python 3 at a minimum. I'm calling it like this:

```
// the -u is for unbuffered output
String[] pythonCommand = {"python", "-u", "script.py"};
ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder(pythonCommand);
Process pr = pb.start();
```

It works completely fine on Windows, and when I define script.py to print out the Python version with `sys.version_info` it tells me that I am running Python 3.6.2

However, on my friend's Macbook, the script doesn't work and `sys.version_info` shows Python 2.7.1. She installed Python 3 using homebrew with `brew install python3`. When she runs `python3 scriptname.py` from terminal, it runs on Python 3.6.2 but `python scriptname.py` runs on Python 2.7.1 from Terminal.

Because of that, I thought I could just change the Java ProcessBuilder command to be

```
String[] pythonCommand = {"python3", "-u", "script.py"}; // python3
```

if the OS name doesn't start with Windows, but that command doesn't work from Java's processbuilder on Mac OS—it throws

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I'm thinking this is a problem with the path that the ProcessBuilder is using to run Python, does that sound right? Maybe I need to try to use virtualenv to run Python 3 on Mac, but I have no idea how to do that. Or, could it be something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going away from this approach entirely since it relied on Python and all the required modules being installed on the user's computer. Instead, I packaged my Python scripts into executables with Pyinstaller, put them into the Java resources folder, and called the compiled executables from the Java ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew does not always link the actual python3 executable to a directory that is in the `PATH`. You should check this with the terminal.

On my MacBook the python3 is linked at `/usr/local/bin/python3`

```
xvolks@localhost ~> ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xvolks  admin  35 19 aoû 00:02 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.2/bin/python3
```

If the link is missing you can use the command `brew link python3`
to create it.

Comment: When we run that, it tries to link the Python 3 in in Celler/python3 to some `/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.6` folder instead of the '/usr/local/bin/python3' folder, and it failed in doing so because that '2to3-3.6' folder was already there.

Comment: So try to create the link yourself in terminal with the command `ln -s ...`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's not the best solution. We are looking for an easy way to be able to run our projects scripts on Python 3 with Windows, Linux, and Mac, and that seems like that would be unnecessary work to do on potentially every Unix system we use. I think I'm going to try to run Python in a virtual environment in our project using pipenv.